# A question about fiberbundles in algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I hope this question is not too simple:

Let $F,E,B$ complex algebraic varieties such that there exists a fiber bundle
$$F\to E\to B$$
where all morphisms are assumed to be algebraic.

Question:

If $F$ and $B$ are projective (resp. quasi-projective) is then total space $E$ also projective (resp. quasi-projective)

I think both statements are wrong but I can't construct  counterexamples.

Comment: What's your definition of a fiber bundle?

Comment: I would say locally trivial in the Zariski topology!

Comment: Locally trivial meaning locally a product? This is an extremely restrictive notion; usually one uses the étale topology. Also, if you want an analogue of the topological notion of fiber bundle even having isomorphic fibers may be too strong. For example, a smooth projective morphism is topologically a fiber bundle, but does not have isomorphic fibers in general.

Comment: I think Hartshorne Proposition 7.10. of Chapter II is related your question

Comment: Ok, i am sorry but maybe my question was to naive. First i really thought about the obvious (naive) definition of a fiber bundle in the Zariski topology, of course if there are nice results in the form of: We have an algebraic morphism $E\to B$ which is a fiber bundle in the  etale topology. If $F$ and $B$ are projective then is $ E$ (for maybe a very restrictive class of varieties $B$ and $F$) then so is $E$ I would be glad to hear about it. @ZhuangXiaobo thank you for the reference! – O. Straser 3 hours ago



Comment: I edited my comment above and replaced Zariski by etale.